# zabbix server connecting to mariadb host: can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mariadb, zabbix

I have a Dockerized Zabbix server (3.4) connecting to a CentOS 7 host w/ Mariadb.

This one works fine:

```
# zabbix_get -s <ipOfRemoteHost> -p 10050 -k mysql.version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

This one does not:

```
# zabbix_get -s <ipOfRemoteHost> -p 10050 -k mysql.ping
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

From `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/userparameter_mysql.conf`:

```
UserParameter=mysql.version,mysql -V
UserParameter=mysql.ping,HOME=/etc/zabbix mysqladmin ping | grep -c alive
```

It does read the .my.cnf in the HOME dir, when change `host=localhost` to `host=127.0.0.1` I get:

```
# zabbix_get -s <ipOfRemoteHost> -p 10050 -k mysql.ping
mysqladmin: connect to server at '127.0.0.1' failed
error: 'Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13)'
Check that mysqld is running on 127.0.0.1 and that the port is 3306.
You can check this by doing 'telnet 127.0.0.1 3306'
```

Also tried adding the username and password directly in the command, but same result:

```
UserParameter=mysql.ping,mysqladmin -uroot --password="mypassword" ping | grep -c alive
```

Running that command on the host works fine:

```
mysqladmin -uroot --password="mypassword"  ping | grep -c alive
1
```

The agent itself seems to run fine:

```
$ sudo -u zabbix zabbix_agentd -t mysql.ping
mysql.ping                                    [t|1]
```

Socket is available:

```
# ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
srwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql 0 Nov  5 18:01 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Process details:

```
# ps -ef | grep mysqld
mysql     3218     1  0 18:01 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr
mysql     3488  3218 99 18:01 ?        06:08:26 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log --pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
systemd+  6547  6530  0 Oct31 ?        00:06:15 mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_bin
```

Any suggestions?

Note: don't think it is relevant but just in case, on the host I also have a Dockerized mysql running on port 3307

Answer (score 0):

`localhost`/`127.0.0.1` in the container is not the same as `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` on the host, because of cgroup network namespacing. Use proper IP in `.my.cnf` or run container in the host network namespace (`docker run --net host ...`).

If you want to use a socket for MySQL connection from the container, then you will need to use Docker volumes. You may have problems with socket permissions, socket owner, ... I recommend IP connecting approach.

Comment: Not sure I understand Jan. The MariaDB host is a remote system, with port 10050 opened for the zabbix agent. It is my understanding that the zabbix agent is called and then runs the data collecting commands locally.

Comment: I remember that containerized application have to use external IP although while running on the same host running.

Comment: @Daein: do you have details? Where do I put that external IP?

Comment: It’s -p option. This option enable the port forwarding from host or host ip to docker internal port. For example; docker run -p hostip:port:containerport ...snip...

Comment: @Daein: I don't understand. They are not running on the same host. The Zabbix server is Dockerized, the rest is not. Agent runs on regular CentOS server, with regular MariaDB install. The agent collects all info fine, except the mysql data.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is selinux. selinux is prohibiting the Zabbix agent from accessing the mysql socket file and possibly other resources.

Run `tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log` while you try `zabbix_get` and you'll see the denials in real-time.

Then you'll need to devise an selinux policy that enables access as needed.